# Android Stock Browser Not Override Accept-Language

Tags: android, browser, header, xmlhttprequest, http-accept-language

I have an Android Samsung tablet and I test this simple xhr request on its stock browser.

```
var url = "http://172.20.10.10:3030/whatever";
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "es-CL");
oReq.send();
```

Then, on my node server.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("HEADERS : ", req.headers['accept-language']);
    res.status(200).end();
    next();
});
```

I receive this header :

```
fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Because my tablet is in french.

Is it possible to override this header on an Android Stock Browser ? To have  :

```
es-CL,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

I reproduce too on Ucall, OnePlus...

Thank you !

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue and didn't find any other references on the internet.

Comment: same issue, also cannot find any more information around. Did you manage to solve?